# What happens to AppGroups after with app transfer?

Tags: ios, ios-app-group, app-transfer

I recently changed my developer account from account A to account B. I have successfully transferred my applications.

With transfer of applications my app group was not migrated. So I deleted the app group from account A and recreate it in account B with the exact same identifier.

**Question -**

When I push an update for my app with Account B, will I be able to access the data in app group which was created when app was part of Account A ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , when you install an app in a device the only thing that creates a duplicate of it is changing bundle-id so as long as the bundle-identifier  of the app , all extensions and the group is the same , access to old userDefaults shared data will be valid , as evidence **Apple** makes bundle-ids unique for any app to any developer , and not unique within apps of the same developer , so developer actor is not on the scene when installing an app but for sure it tracks that the app for him to upload crashes and other analytic-s

Comment: can you perhaps provide some references to back it up?

Comment: @Milan you can test this by createing 2 apps from 2 different accounts store in defaults of 1 and when installing the second print current key of the defaults with same bundle-id

Comment: not that I don't believe you, but I think the answer would benefit from a reference to some official statement from Apple

Comment: @Sh_Khan: Marking your answer as correct one. I tried this and it works fine, I was able to access app group container after transfer.

Comment: @Sandy Happy coding , glad it helps